# How can I prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$ in a Hilbert space does not converge in norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

> Let $X$ be a Hilbert space an $(e_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be a complete orthonormal set (i.e. a basis). Then define $$F_n:X\rightarrow X;~~~x\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k$$I want to prove that $||F_n-F_m||=1$ if $n\neq m$.

W.l.o.g. we can assume $m<n$, then $$\begin{align}||F_n-F_m||&=\sup_{||x||=1}||F_n(x)-F_m(x)||\\&=\sup_{||x||=1} \left|\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n \langle x,e_k\rangle e_k \right|\right|\\&=\sup_{||x||=1} \left(\sum_{k=m+1}^n |\langle x, e_k\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\end{align}$$

Now somehow I don't see why the last equality should be true. I read something that it has to do with the fact that $(e_k)$ is orthonormal, but I don't see why.

Can maybe someone explain me the last equality?

Comment: Observe that for $n>m$ we have $(F_n-F_m)(e_{m+1})=e_{m+1}.$ Hence $\|F_n-F_m\|\ge 1.$ Actually $F_n-F_m$ is a nonzero orthogonal projection.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes so I got the other inequality, the only problem is this equality here.

Comment: You have proved that $\|F_n-F_m\|\le 1$ as $\sum_{k=m+1}^n|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2\le \|x\|^2$ by the Bessel inequality.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes but the other one was not a problem, therefore I also did not wrote it in the question

Comment: So you are done with $\|F_n-F_m\|=1$ for $n\neq m.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes now since Davide Giraudo gave showed me why the equality is true I'm done

Comment: The argument given in my first comment looks simpler, at least for me.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but you still need to go to this point where I went in the original question to apply this argument right?

Comment: It is obvious that $F_ne_{m+1}=e_{m+1}$ and $F_me_{m+1}=0,$ by orthonormality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha_j:= \langle x,e_j\rangle$.
By definition of the norm
$$
\left\lVert\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_k  e_k\right\rVert^2
=\left\langle \sum_{j=m+1}^n \alpha_j  e_j,\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_k e_k\right\rangle
$$
and by bilinearity of inner product,
$$
\left\lVert\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_k  e_k\right\rVert^2
=\sum_{j=m+1}^n\sum_{k=m+1}^n \alpha_j\overline{\alpha_k } \left\langle  e_j,  e_k\right\rangle
$$
and by orthonormality, $\left\langle  e_j,  e_k\right\rangle=1$ if $j=k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am still stuck at some point. Is $\langle e_j, \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k\rangle=\langle x, e_k\rangle \langle e_j, e_k\rangle$? Shouldn't it be $\overline{\langle x, e_k\rangle} \langle e_j, e_k\rangle$?

Comment: I assumed the Hilbert space to be real, but indeed if it is a complex one we need the conjugate.

Comment: And then it depends upon the convention you chose for your hermitian product (seemingly linear w.r.t. the left variable and antilinear w.r.t. the right one, after your comment).

Comment: Ah right, but since we don't have any information I assume it to be complex and then it gives me what I want. Thanks

Comment: Yes, my comment also assumes it to be complex, but there are [2 $\ne$ conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Convention_variant) in that case. NB DavideGiraudo, your answer would be more readable if you wrote everywhere $y_i$ instead of $\langle x,e_i\rangle.$

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right.